# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter can't retrieve data from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm trying to show Blog Posts on my MainActivity (Home page). But Homepage Nothing shows I mean Homepage is empty.

**Firebase database structure:**

[image]

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private RecyclerView mBlogList;
    private DatabaseReference mDataRef;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BlogInfo, ViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started!");
        mDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BlogApp").child("Posts");
        mBlogList = findViewById(R.id.blogListId);
        mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BlogInfo> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<BlogInfo>()
                .setQuery(mDataRef, BlogInfo.class).build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BlogInfo, ViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull BlogInfo model) {

                String imgUrl = model.getImage();
                Picasso.get().load(imgUrl).into(holder.post_image);
                holder.post_title.setText(model.getTitle());
                holder.post_desc.setText(model.getDescription());

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: initialized!");
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_blog_item, parent, false);
                ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
                return holder;
            }
        };
        mBlogList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: init");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: stop Blog list");
    }

    // ViewHolder Class
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private static final String TAG = "ViewHolder";
        TextView post_title;
        TextView post_desc;
        ImageView post_image;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.d(TAG, "ViewHolder: Initialized!");
            post_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postTitleId);
            post_desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postDescId);
            post_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImageId);
        }
    }
}
```

**BlogInfo.class:**

```
public class BlogInfo {
    private String description;
    private String image;
    private String title;

    public BlogInfo() {}

    public BlogInfo(String title, String description, String image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {return title;}

    public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

    public String getDescription() {return description;}

    public void setDescription(String description) {this.description = description;}

    public String getImage() {return image;}

    public void setImage(String image) {this.image = image;}
}
```

This is my first time I'm trying to use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to retrieve data from Firebase Database. But I don't know where the problem is. I tried to debug also but the compiler won't enter into `onCreateViewHolder` or `onBindViewHolder` function. But I'm totally following [FirebaseUI for Realtime Database](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter) reference.

Comment: Have you tried to comment the following line of code `mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);`?

Comment: Your code is fine. Please add also your .XML file.

Comment: Oh I see it's worked now. After //mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true); make comment this line. thanks bro.

Comment: I can't belive this is the solution. really thanks @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need to remove the following line of code:

```
mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

This is needed only when you want your `RecyclerView` to have a fixed size. In your case is not necessary.

Comment: Yes I understand, there was't any fixed number of posts for that the issue occured.